Cropping and resampling distorts raster
I've been struggling to find out why my raster cropping isn't working. I've included the raw raster files here so it should be a fully reproducible example.
I'm trying to implement the following snippet from R in Python:
bps.dat <- 'LC16_BPS_200.tif'
soils.dat <- 'CONUS_SSURGO_soils-002.tif'
ex1 <- c(-2362425, -2131113, 2301888, 2447813)
r <- raster(bps.dat)
bps.tile <- crop(r, ex1)
tmp.extent <- projectExtent(bps.tile, raster(soils.dat))
soil.tile <- crop(raster(soils.dat), tmp.extent)
soil.tile <- raster::projectRaster(soil.tile, bps.tile, method = 'ngb')
soil.tile <- raster::resample(soil.tile, bps.tile, method = 'ngb')

Here is my attempt in python:
import geopandas as gpd
import rioxarray
import rasterio
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import box
from pathlib import Path
from rasterio import warp
import xarray
import pandas as pd

def crop_raster(raster_loc: Path, extent: list, extent_crs: str) -> xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray:
    raster_crs = rasterio.open(raster_loc).meta['crs']
    # Create a bounding box from extent
    bbox = box(extent[0], extent[2], extent[1], extent[3])
    geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': bbox}, index=[0], crs=extent_crs)
    geo = geo.to_crs(raster_crs)
    with rioxarray.open_rasterio(raster_loc, masked=True) as dataset: # type: ignore
        clipped = dataset.rio.clip(geo.geometry.values, raster_crs, from_disk=True) # type: ignore
    return clipped
    
def reproject_raster(dst_raster: Path, src_raster: Path, output_path: Path) -> Path:
    with rasterio.open(src_raster) as src:
        with rasterio.open(dst_raster) as r1:
            transform, width, height = warp.calculate_default_transform(
                src.crs, r1.meta['crs'], src.width, src.height, *src.bounds, dst_width=r1.width, dst_height=r1.height)
            kwargs = src.meta.copy()
            kwargs.update({
                'crs': r1.meta['crs'],
                'transform': transform,
                'height': r1.height,
                'width': r1.width
            })

            with rasterio.open(output_path, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
                rasterio.warp.reproject(
                    source=rasterio.band(src, 1),
                    destination=rasterio.band(dst, 1),
                    src_transform=src.transform,
                    src_crs=src.crs,
                    dst_transform=transform,
                    dst_crs=r1.meta['crs'],
                    resampling=rasterio.warp.Resampling.nearest)
    return output_path

def crop_and_reproject(raster_filepath: Path, imitate_raster: Path, intermediate_output_filepath: Path, final_output_filepath: Path, extent: list[float], extent_crs: str) -> None:
    tile_tmp = crop_raster(raster_filepath, extent, extent_crs)
    with rasterio.open(raster_filepath) as raster:
        out_meta = raster.profile
    tmp_array = tile_tmp.to_numpy()
    tile_shape = tmp_array.shape
    out_meta.update({"height": tile_shape[1],
                    "width": tile_shape[2],
                    "transform": tile_tmp.rio.transform()})
    with rasterio.open(intermediate_output_filepath, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
        dest.write(tmp_array)
    reproject_raster(imitate_raster, intermediate_output_filepath, final_output_filepath)
    return

extent = [-2362425, -2131113, 2301888, 2447813]
bps_filepath = 'LC16_BPS_200.tif'
soils_filepath = 'CONUS_SSURGO_soils-002.tif'

with rasterio.open(bps_filepath) as bps_raster:
    bps_raster_crs = bps_raster.meta['crs']
# Crop the BPS raster to the defined extent
bps_tile_raster = crop_raster(bps_filepath, extent, bps_raster_crs)
bps_tile = bps_tile_raster.to_numpy()

with rasterio.open(bps_filepath) as bps_raster:
    out_meta = bps_raster.profile
# Update profile with new size and transform
out_meta.update({"height": bps_tile.shape[1],
             "width": bps_tile.shape[2],
             "transform": bps_tile_raster.rio.transform()})
reshaped_bps_tile_filepath = 'reshaped_bps_tile.tif'
soils_tile_path_intermediate = 'soils_intermediate.tif'
soils_tile_path = 'soils_tile.tif'

with rasterio.open(reshaped_bps_tile_filepath, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(bps_tile)
crop_and_reproject(soils_filepath, \
                   reshaped_bps_tile_filepath, \
                   soils_tile_path_intermediate, \
                   soils_tile_path, \
                   extent, \
                   bps_raster_crs)
with rasterio.open(soils_tile_path) as soils_raster:
    soils_tile = soils_raster.read(1)

When I visualize the output of the R script and the python one, they look almost identical. However, looking at the values for each, they definitely aren't:
pd.Series(np.ravel(soils_tile)).value_counts()

yields

0: 11,837,161
1: 407,754
2: 247,425
3: 10,477,247
4: 12,905,849
5: 1,638,579

while table(getValues(soil.tile)) yields

0: 11,503,362
1: 396,551
2: 240,772
3: 10,192,343
4: 12,553,099
5: 1,593,873

In trying to deduce what is going wrong, I noticed that when I run the initial clipping operation (i.e. if I only run the crop_raster function above) on the soils raster, the array is quite different in dimension from when I run it on the bps raster: (4865, 7501) vs (4865, 7711). My best guess is that in order to get the arrays to be the same size (which I must), it's stretching and distorting the cells in some way.
Both the raw rasters have the same CRS (EPSG 5070) so no reprojection is actually happening. However, I noticed they have slightly different transforms:

bps: 'transform': Affine(30.0, 0.0, -2362425.0, 0.0, -30.0, 3177435.0)
soils:'transform': Affine(30.0, 0.0, -2356114.034600001, 0.0, -30.0, 3172588.6865)

This is the best I could do to figure out what's wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm really stuck on this.
